Interfacing optical sensor with Teensy
For a while, I have been learning practical control systems.
I found this MIT course on the internet and I am trying to build this on my own.
It is basically a speed control system using TRCT5000 as the sensor and a small dc motor with a reflective plate.

The following picture shows sensor interface with the microcontroller board.

From the image, I understand that the output is connected in common collector configuration. But, I can’t figure out how the resistor value was calculated as 11k. The output of the sensor is connected via an integrated circuit to the MCU.
Also, upon carefully going through the images, I found the marking on the CHIP as AAKW - AN OP AMP FROM ANALOG DEVICES(MAX4232AKA)
I can simply replicate the circuit but I am trying to sort of reverse engineer the system and could someone help me how to calculate different values in the system ? Should I consider input & output impedance while to understand why the circuit is connected in the way it is built? What would happen if I don’t use op amp here ? Should I consider emitter  current from the sensor ?
Note - from the circuit I can calculate that the led current is ~20mA.
Please share any similar kind of links to learn about control systems in this way.

It's almost certain that the sensor resistor was not "calculated". Read the sensor data sheet and notice the CTR of 10%. If you use a mirror to reflect the LED light, you'd get about 2 mA out of the phototransistor, and 11k would give you about 22 volts. (with a supply voltage greater than 22V, of course). Instead, you have white plastic arms, which are overall pretty bright, but give a diffuse reflection and a lot of light loss. Assuming a mirror says you would want about a 1.5k to give 3 volts. Without a mirror yhou need a larger resistor, but how much? I suspect they did trial and error.

How do I select the resistor value such that it operates in saturation?

@Theja Exactly as WhatRoughBeast said: Trial and error. Calculating it would require knowing details you don't know, but getting it wrong doesn't hurt anything. So try it and find out what works adequately--this isn't something that needs to be optimized. A resistance too high will make it too sensitive, and a resistance too low means it won't be sensitive enough. Neither of these will damage anything; it just won't do what it's supposed to.

"11k would give you about 22 volts. (with a supply voltage greater than 22V, of course)" - I could not understand this. Independent of the resistor value, will the collector current be 2mA ? For a BJT, in the same configuration, with Vb of some value, Ve ~ Vb - 0.7
Incase of optoisolator, Does Ve is pulled up to Vcc when light falls  ? I am confused totally.

@Theja - " Independent of the resistor value, will the collector current be 2mA ?" As long as the load resistance is not so high that voltage across it gets close to the supply voltage, yes. That is why the device has a CTR (Current Transfer Ratio) listed.  Basically, a phototransistor in this configuration acts like a transistor whose base drive is determined by the number of photons hitting the die. The photons knock electrons out of the base material and into the base-emitter junction. Vb doesn't really apply here.

@Theja - Hearth is entirely correct. At your present level of knowledge do not try to do this stuff theoretically, at least not in any definitive sense. Get hold of a sensor and start messing around with it. OTH, you should definitely do the calculations for the LED current theoretically so you don't burn out the LED.

I really understand and appreciate your suggestion. But I just want to know how one would size a resistor for reflective optocouplers.
